# ssh local port forwarding not working

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

**My goal:**

I have a computer in a location A, let's call it host-A.
I have a computer in a location B (host-B) running an ssh server, and I can ssh from host-A into host-B. I want to access a website on the web browser of host-A, say http://example.com/ via an ssh tunnel through host-B.

**What I did:**

In host-A, I type `ssh -v -N -L 8080:example.com:80 host-B`.
I can check using `netstat  --inet -lnp` that ssh is indeed listening on 127.0.0.1:8080, with foreign address 0.0.0.0:*.
In host-B, I can access example.com.
Hence in host-A browser (firefox here), when I type the url "http://localhost:8080/", I should access the example.com webpage.

**My questions:**

When I do this, I actually get a 404 not found. Yet, in the shell in which I issued the "ssh -L", I see some logs, for instance:

`debug1: Connection to port 8080 forwarding to example.com port 80 requested.`

(1) So what happened here? I did exactly the same (except using example.com) as, e.g., [this example on local port forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding).

When I try with "www.ubuntuforums.org" (so `ssh -v -N -L 8080:www.ubuntuforums.org:80 host-B` in host-A), http://localhost:8080/ actually takes me to "https://www.canonical.com/". (2) Why is that?

When I try with `ssh -v -N -L 8080:www.stackoverflow.com:80 host-B`, I get:

`Fastly error: unknown domain: localhost. Please check that this domain has been added to a service.
Details: cache-cdg20728-CDG`
(3) Again, why? So many mysteries for me here...